# Description items inside table?

Tags: tables, lists, cv, description

I'm new to LaTeX and trying to create a resumé. I know there are alternatives like moderncv but I'd like to try creating it from scratch.

I would like to have dates displayed on the left, sort of like this http://www.artbizblog.com/2010/11/tables-for-resume.html

Is there an nice way of doing this?

Tried to create description lists inside of a table but it doesn't work.

```
\begin{tabular}{l|c}
    \textbf{date should be here} &
    \begin{description}
        \item[item should be here]
        description should be here
    \end{description} \\
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: You could use `\begin{tabular}{…} Date should be here & Item should be here & Description should be here \end{tabular}`. By the way… which should be the formatting of the Item? I don't see the item in the link you provided (just two columns: date and description).

Comment: I would like to have date and item as two columns and description below the item, if possible? Was thinking of writing a short description/comment about each item.

Comment: But as you said, perhaps I don't need the list at all, I could just use a table with some formatting :)
I started out with a list and then was trying to think of how to get the date on the left, then tried combining it with a table but I guess a table is all I need lol.

Comment: May be something like `\begin{tabular}{l p{6cm} Date should be here & \textbf{Item should be here} \\ & Description should be here \end{tabular}`?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a macro for it:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}

%%% syntax 
%%% \cventry{<year>}{<item>}[<optional>|<description>]

\NewDocumentCommand\cventry{mmo}{%
\IfValueTF{#3}{%
   \noindent
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{2cm}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}%
      {\bfseries #1} & {%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
      \begin{description}[nolistsep,font=\sffamily\bfseries, leftmargin=*,style=nextline]%
         \item[#2] \raggedright #3
      \end{description}%
      \end{minipage}%
      }%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
}%
{%
   \noindent%
  \begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{}p{2cm}p{\dimexpr\linewidth-2cm-2\tabcolsep\relax}@{}}%
      {\bfseries #1} & {%
      \begin{minipage}[t]{\linewidth}%
      \begin{description}[nolistsep,font=\sffamily\bfseries, leftmargin=*,style=nextline]%
         \item[#2]
      \end{description}%
      \end{minipage}%
      }%
  \end{tabular*}%
  \par\addvspace{0.5\baselineskip}%
}%
}%

\begin{document}
\cventry{2014}{Education}%[some text here]
\cventry{2014}{I worked some times}[As any dedicated reader can clearly see]
\end{document}
```

[image]